# How to apply the line break in a PGFPlots line chart

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, line-breaking

I am writing an academic article and I have a large graph that should be reduced in its size to fit a one column width if possible. I was wondering if it would be possible to apply different line breaks in the axis so to decrease the width of the graph and more specifically between 25 and 45 in the Y axis and 1000 and 2000 in the X axis.

Attached a MWE.

```
\documentclass[10pt, conference, final, a4paper, twocolumn, oneside]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\pgfplotsset{width=7cm,compat=1.8} 
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}



\begin{document}


\begin{figure*}[!h]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    %title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
    height=7cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    xlabel={Batch Size},
    ylabel={Cost per part},
    xmin=0, xmax=2250,
    ymin=0, ymax=50,
    xtick={0,200,500,800,1000,2000},
    ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,45},
    yticklabel={\geneuro\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}},
    legend pos=north east,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    grid style=dashed,
]
\addplot + [
    color=blue,
    smooth,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,45.14)(200,22.63)(300,15.12)(400,11.37)(500,9.12)(800,5.74)(1000,4.61)(2000,2.36)};
\addplot + [
    color=black,
    smooth,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,11.25)(200,10.58)(300,10.35)(400,10.24)(500,10.17)(800,10.07)(1000,10.04)(2000,9.97)};

\addplot + [
    color=orange,
    smooth,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,14.70)(200,7.38)(300,4.93)(400,3.71)(500,2.98)(800,1.88)(1000,1.51)(2000,0.78)};
\addplot + [
    color=darkgray,
    smooth,
    ]
    coordinates {
    (100,2.79)(200,1.45)(300,1.00)(400,0.78)(500,0.71)(800,0.61)(1000,0.57)(2000, 0.51)};

    \legend{One, Two, Three, Four}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption[Break-Even-Analysis]{Break-Even-Analysis .} \label{fig:break-even-analysis}
\end{figure*}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks like this is code is based on a template on sharelatex: https://de.sharelatex.com/learn/Pgfplots_package

Answer (score 1):

One way to save space would be to use `symbolic x coords`. Have a look at the comments in the code on how it works.

```
% used PGFPlots v1.14
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        %title={Temperature dependence of CuSO$_4\cdot$5H$_2$O solubility},
        height=7cm,    % <-- I would reduce this size to make it look more square
        width=0.5\textwidth,    % <-- changed to `0.5\textwidth' to simulate on column width
        xlabel={Batch Size},
        ylabel={Cost per part},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
%        % we don't need these
%        xmin=0, xmax=2250,
%        ymin=0, ymax=50,
        % show only ticks at the data point ...
        xtick={data},
        % ... and use symblic coordinates
        symbolic x coords={
            100,200,300,400,500,800,1000,2000%
        },
        % so the `xticklabels' don't overlap, rotate them
        xticklabel style={
            rotate=90,
        },
%        % I think we don't need either
%        ytick={0,5,10,15,20,25,45},
        % ---------------------------------------------------------------------
        yticklabel={\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}\,€},
        legend pos=north east,
        ymajorgrids=true,
        xmajorgrids=true,
        grid style=dashed,
        smooth,     % <-- moved it here, because it is all `\addplot's in common
    ]
        \addplot+ [color=blue] coordinates {
            (100,45.14)(200,22.63)(300,15.12)(400,11.37)(500,9.12)(800,5.74)(1000,4.61)(2000,2.36)};
        \addplot+ [color=black] coordinates {
            (100,11.25)(200,10.58)(300,10.35)(400,10.24)(500,10.17)(800,10.07)(1000,10.04)(2000,9.97)
        };
        \addplot+ [color=orange] coordinates {
            (100,14.70)(200,7.38)(300,4.93)(400,3.71)(500,2.98)(800,1.88)(1000,1.51)(2000,0.78)
        };
        \addplot+ [color=darkgray] coordinates {
            (100,2.79)(200,1.45)(300,1.00)(400,0.78)(500,0.71)(800,0.61)(1000,0.57)(2000, 0.51)
        };

        \legend{One, Two, Three, Four}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result of above code]